# ClickOnce multiple deployment location options

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, clickonce

I have an internal app that is deployed through `ClickOnce`.  We have 5 branches and our vpn lines between us are quite slow.  I would like to explore the possibility of publishing my app to each of the 5 branch servers.  My understanding of `ClickOnce` is that my simplest approach will be to manually change my Publishing and Installation Folder for each instance.  Is that correct?  Is there a better way?

I see this post, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907051/deploying-clickonce-application-to-multiple-servers), but it doesn't address any issues I would face if I chose to deploy separately to each of our five branches.

Answer (score 5):

We also have to publish a clickOnce to multiple locations and you are quite right you do have to do each one separately and change the locations by hand.  You can however build this into a batch script.  We did the same and I cant give out too much info as we have tight IP rules but basically you can use msbuild (there is a /t:publishOnly switch) and you can set the install url and publish directory as well.  You need to investigate which files are created by VS (off the top of my head you at least need the Publish Template).  we then wrote a simple c# app to do the ftp transfer and you have basically copied the VS process.  I admit it is a pain but as long as you get the steps right you can simply run the batch file and it works.
The msbuild switches of interest are /t:PublishOnly /p:PublishDir={your publish directory} /p:InstallUrl={your install url} and obviously /p:Configuration={the config to use}